# python - 2 lists, and finding maximum product from 2 lists

Tags: python, list

I have two lists made of numbers(integers); both have 2 million unique elements.

I want to find number a from list 1 and b from list 2, that -

```
1)a*b should be maximized.
2)a*b has to be smaller than certain limit.
```

here's what I came up with:

```
maxpq = 0
nums = sorted(nums, reverse=True)
nums2 = sorted(nums2, reverse=True)
for p in nums:
    n = p*dropwhile(lambda q: p*q>sqr, nums2).next()
    if n>maxpq:
        maxpq=n
print maxpq
```

any suggestions?
edit : my method is too slow. It would take more than one day.

Comment: Does what you have work? if it doesn't, what's wrong with it?

Comment: It is too slow. :D list 1 has 2000000 elements, which means from my code 2000000 comparisons has to be done - the speed of comparison on my ivy bridge is around 1~2 comparison(s) / sec. this won't go well..

Comment: You should probably mentions that in your question, because it's pretty vague at the moment.

Comment: Why not just do `max(nums) * max(nums2)`?

Comment: @JoelCornett `a*b has to be smaller than certain limit.`

Comment: Why not sort the lists and iterate over one and binary fuzzy search for the complement? (I think this could be a good interview question)

Comment: I think sort is slowing down the process due to multiple iterations, a simple double forloop over the unordered lists might be much quicker in your case..

Comment: @ppetrid sorting is only done once.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget what is binary fuzzy search?

Comment: @thkang one for each list indeed, but I mean the iterations inside the sorting algorithm

Comment: @thkang: binary search for a number similar to the number being searched for. In this case, similarity would be defined as "at most the number being searched for"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a linear-time solution (after sorting):

```
def maximize(a, b, lim):
    a.sort(reverse=True)
    b.sort()
    found = False
    best = 0
    j = 0
    for i in xrange(len(a)):
        while j < len(b) and a[i] * b[j] < lim:
            found = True
            if a[i]*b[j] > best:
                best, n1, n2 = a[i] * b[j], a[i], b[j]
            j += 1
    return found and (best, n1, n2)
```

Simply put:

- start from the highest and lowest from each list
- while their product is less than the target, advance the small-item
- once the product becomes bigger than your goal, advance the big-item until it goes below again

This way, you're guaranteed to go through each list only once. It'll return `False` if it couldn't find anything small enough, otherwise it'll return the product and the pair that produced it.

Sample output:

```
a = [2, 5, 4, 3, 6]
b = [8, 1, 5, 4]
maximize(a, b, 2)   # False
maximize(a, b, 3)   # (2, 2, 1)
maximize(a, b, 10)  # (8, 2, 4)
maximize(a, b, 100) # (48, 6, 8)
```

Comment: oops, I forgot a condition. try now.

Comment: thanks. it returns correct value and faster than bisect module. `11564.4234058 ms` for my bisect, `5679.87929394 ms` for yours. :D

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for everyone's advices and ideas. I finally came up with useful solution.  Mr inspectorG4dget shone a light on this one.

It uses `bisect` module from python's standard library.

edit : bisect module does binary search in order to find insert position of a value in a sorted list. therefore It reduces number of compares, unlike my previous solution.

http://www.sparknotes.com/cs/searching/binarysearch/section1.rhtml

```
import bisect

def bisect_find(num1, num2, limit):
    num1.sort()    
    max_ab = 0

    for a in num2:
        complement = limit / float(a)
        b = num1[bisect.bisect(num1, complement)-1]

        if limit > a*b > max_ab:
            max_ab=b*a

    return max_ab
```

Comment: bisect does [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm), the first paragraph on [this page](http://www.sparknotes.com/cs/searching/binarysearch/section1.rhtml) is a good explanation - it's fast because it only has to look at a small number of items in the list (it's first step is to look at the middle value, and see if the target is before-or-after that point, then one half of the list can be ignored)

Answer (score 0):

This might be faster.

```
def doer(L1, L2, ceil):
    max_c = ceil - 1
    L1.sort(reverse=True)
    L2.sort(reverse=True)
    big_a = big_b = big_c = 0

    for a in L1:
        for b in L2:
            c = a * b
            if c == max_c:
                return a, b
            elif max_c > c > big_c:
                big_a = a
                big_b = b
                big_c = c

    return big_a, big_b


print doer([1, 3, 5, 10], [8, 7, 3, 6], 60)
```

Note that it sorts the lists in-place; this is faster, but may or may not be appropriate in your scenario.

Comment: Thanks for your help but unfortunately I don't see any significant speed-up.

Comment: I imagine there's some great algorithm out there, just waiting for us :P

Comment: Ah, the binary search might be the best

Comment: Ack, I go write a binary search algorithm, then come back and find the problem solved :P